# Why isn't my toggle button working in bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to view some content in the mobile view in the `navbar`.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">

                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <div class="navbar-brand">
                        <span>Food, LLC</span>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#" class="visible-xs">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="visible-xs">Link 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="visible-xs">Link 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </nav>

    </header>
    <script src="jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My output:

[image: this]

When I press the toggle button, nothing happens. Why? *(I am using Twitter Bootstrap 3.3.7)*

Comment: Are you sure that jQuery and the Bootstrap JS files are being included successfully? Your HTML seems to match the Bootstrap docs

Comment: maybe can replace your jquery script and bootstrap from the official docs, that you can find here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/#separate

Comment: are you sure your `script.js` does not conflict with Bootstrap/jQuery? With the code you provided the toggle correctly works, even with your versions of Bootstrap/jQuery, see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oyz01hmp/